# Customizing pgfuml (distances)

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I'm using [pgfuml](https://code.google.com/p/pgf-umlsd/) to create some sequence diagrams. As you can already see in the examples on the pgf-uml Homepage, diagramms get very crammed if you insert many descriptions. Text and arrows overlap and are hard to read because they overleap each other.

I'm no experienced Latex user and I can't figure out how to change the pgf-umlsd.sty a little bit so the diagrams get a bit straightened and better to read. Can somebody tell me how to fix this, e.g. increase the space between elements?

For example: on the examples page is shown:

```
<-----------------
       Update()
----------------->
```

How could I increase the distance between these arrows to straighten the diagram?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to fix this, because magic numbers were used everywhere in the code. Consider the line `\draw[dotted] (inst\t) -- ++(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-2.2*\unitfactor);`. This `\unitfactor` shows up in numerous math operations with various coefficients.

A starting attempt would be to modify `\unitfactor` (default `0.6`) inside the `sequencediagram` environment to stretch the diagram:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}
\begin{sequencediagram}
\def\unitfactor{0.8}
\newthread{ss}{:SimulationServer}
\newinst{ctr}{:SimControlNode}
\newinst{ps}{:PhysicsServer}
\newinst[1]{sense}{:SenseServer}
\begin{call}{ss}{Initialize()}{sense}{}
\end{call}
\begin{call}{ss}{Update()}{ps}{}
\end{call}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But as you can see, the return from the update call does not point into the SimulationServer thread as it should. This is because some of the magic numbers used to calculate this position in the code assume the default `\unitfactor` of `0.6`. This would require major surgery (essentially a rewrite) to correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be use `\postlevel` see [manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxeou.png). Note it can be used repeatedly to get more vertical space.

Note that for increase horizontal space you can use `\newinst[10]{a}{ARM}` where `10` is a vertical space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newthread[white]{c}{9555}
        \newinst[10]{a}{ARM}

        \begin{call}{c}{
            \shortstack{
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong\\
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong\\
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong}
        }
        {a}{
            \shortstack{
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong\\
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong\\
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong}
        }
        \postlevel
        \postlevel
        \postlevel
        \postlevel
        \end{call}

        \begin{call}{c}{aaa}{a}{bbb}
        \end{call}
    \end{sequencediagram}

    \caption{Find Me typical use case}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249652/93758) may be helpful