# Text overlapping in a Sequence Diagram

Tags: pgf-umlsd

Is it possible to prevent text overlapping in this MWE?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}
\begin{sequencediagram}
\newthread[white]{u}{User}
{\tikzset{inststyle/.append style={drop shadow={top color=gray, bottom color=white}, rounded corners=2.0ex}}
\newinst[3]{b}{Browser}%
\newinst[3]{a}{Another}%
\newinst[3]{l}{Last One}%
}%
\begin{sdblock}{Loop}{\parbox[b]{10.0cm}{Long Description here!!! Long Description here!!! Long Description here!!! Long Description here!!!}}
\begin{call}{u}{\parbox[b]{6.0cm}{\raggedright Long messages Long messages Long messages Long messages Long messageshere!!!}}{l}{}
\end{call}
\end{sdblock}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to the source code for `pgf-umlsd` and noticed that

- The height for items in the `sdblock` is hard coded.  So at this point you are limited to a max of three lines.
- However the height for items in  call has a height option.

So, to fix the overlap, I replaced `parbox` with a `minipage` environment and set the width as needed.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}

\begin{sequencediagram}
\newthread[white]{u}{User}
{\tikzset{inststyle/.append style={drop shadow={top color=gray, bottom color=white}, rounded corners=2.0ex}}
\newinst[3]{b}{Browser}%
\newinst[3]{a}{Another}%
\newinst[3]{l}{Last One}%
}%
\begin{sdblock}{Loop}{\begin{minipage}{3.5cm}{ Long Description here!!! Long Description here!!! Long Description here!!!}\end{minipage}}
\begin{call}[5in]{u}{}{l}{\begin{minipage}{4.2cm}{ Long messages here!!! Long messages here!!! Long messages here!!! Long messages here!!! Long messages here!!! Long messages here!!! Long messages here!!!}\end{minipage}}
\end{call}
\end{sdblock}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be use `\postlevel` see [manual](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-umlsd/pgf-umlsd-manual.pdf). Note it can be used repeatedly to get more vertical space.

Note that for increase horizontal space you can use `\newinst[10]{a}{ARM}` where `10` is a vertical space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newthread[white]{c}{9555}
        \newinst[10]{a}{ARM}

        \begin{call}{c}{
            \shortstack{
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong\\
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong\\
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong}
        }
        {a}{
            \shortstack{
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong\\
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong\\
                looooo ooooo oooooooo oooooooooooo oooooong}
        }
        \postlevel
        \postlevel
        \postlevel
        \postlevel
        \end{call}

        \begin{call}{c}{aaa}{a}{bbb}
        \end{call}
    \end{sequencediagram}

    \caption{Find Me typical use case}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]